# Why Changes failed commit to DB on the second transaction in asp.net core

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, asp.net-core, model

I am working on asp.net core application(like inventory app). I discovered that the first transaction I do when I first load visual studio, the transaction is always successful. but subsequent ones don't work(doesn't save to DB again). Unless I close visual studio. loading it again then transaction works for the first time again but none will work after that.

The method

```
   [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddProduct([FromBody]List<Sale> sales)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var currentUser = await _userManager .GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
                var store = _context.Stores.FirstOrDefault(m => m.ApplicationUserId == currentUser.Id);

                foreach (Sale sale in sales)
                {
                    sale.StoreId = store.Id;
                    sale.ApplicationUserId = currentUser.Id;
                    _context.Sales.Add(sale);
                }
            }
            var status =  _context.SaveChanges();
            return Json(status);
        }
```

Comment: While debugging I discovered that status is 0

Answer (score 0):

I think the approach you're using is what is causing the challenge; How about you try this;

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddProduct([FromBody]List<Sale> sales)
{
      List<Sale> sales_dto = new List<Sale>();
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {

          var currentUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
          var store = _context.Stores.FirstOrDefault(m => m.ApplicationUserId == currentUser.Id);

          foreach (Sale sale in sales)
           {
               sale.StoreId = store.Id;
               sale.ApplicationUserId = currentUser.Id;
               sales_dto.Add(sale);
           }
       }

       // use a try catch
       _context.Sales.AddRange(sales_dto)
       var status =  _context.SaveChanges();
       return Json(status);
}
```

Find the detailed description [here](http://andreyzavadskiy.com/2016/09/20/inserting-into-entity-framework-add-vs-addrange/#:~:targetText=Add()%20vs%20AddRange(),method%20inserts%20an%20IEnumerable%20collection.)

Comment: Thanks, John. sales_dto does not exist in the current context. here ` _context.Sales.AddRange(sales_dto)` So I moved `List<Sale> sales_dto = new List<Sale>();` out of if statement and tried it but `sales_dto` not added to db

Comment: Does `store`  or `currentUser` return anything during debug?

Comment: yes, Store returns store properties and currentUser the current logged in user

Comment: While debugging, When I hover on sale in the foreach, I see all the properties and the values coming from the body.
Also, "sales" is showing count = 1, meaning that the value is being passed

But AJAX return [object Object] error

Comment: Share your `API Request` and `Sale` class